# Find the value of $C$ such that $f(x)$ is... proper?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

> Let us build a customized Beta-typed random variable $X$ with the corresponding density function $$f(x) = C(1+x)^{g_1}(1-x)^{g_2}, \enspace \left|x\right|\leq1, \enspace g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$$
>   Find the value of C such that $f(x)$ is proper.

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by proper here but I assume it refers to the fact that the integral of the density function must  be equal to 1. So I set up the following equation in order to find C:

$$C\int_{-1}^{+1}(1+x)^{g_1}(1-x)^{g_2}dx = 1$$

(The limits are -1 and +1 rather than pos. and neg. infinity since x is only defined between them)

I'm struggling to integrate that expression. I tried integration by parts but ended up with an even harder integral. Am I integrating incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conrad's answer is perfectly good, but I thought you might like something a little more elementary.

Integration by parts shows that:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} (1+x)^{g_{1}}(1-x)^{g_{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{g_{2}}{g_{1}+1}\int_{-1}^{1} (1+x)^{g_{1}+1}(1-x)^{g_{2}-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

By induction, we then get
$$\ldots = \frac{g_{2}(g_{2}-1) \ldots 1}{(g_{1}+1)\ldots (g_{1}+g_{2})}\int_{-1}^{1} (1+x)^{g_{1}+g_{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

which I'm sure you can show is equal to
$$2^{g_{1}+g_{2}+1} \bigg/(g_{1}+g_{2}+1)\binom{g_{1}+g_{2}}{g_{1}}.$$

Comment: What happens to the $g_1 + g_2 + 1$ in the denominator of the evaluated integral? It doesn't cancel for me...

Comment: Oops! Nothing happens to it, I just forgot to write it. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing it by parts isn't going to get you far. I assume you know of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). To do this integral we have to sub in the incomplete Beta function, defined as $$B(x;a,b) = \int_{0}^{z} t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt$$ This of course is just the regular Beta function for $x= 1$. Using this substitution we achieve: $$\left[ 2^{1 + g_1 + g_2} \beta_{\frac{(1 + x)}{2}}( 1 + g_1, 1 + g_2)\right] \Biggr|_{-1}^{1} = \frac{1}{C}$$

Which I'll leave to you to evaluate.